# Yosef and three times scaring his brothers

Tags: pentateuch-chumash, yosef, shevatim-12-tribes, genesis-bereishith, egypt

In the interaction between the Viceroy (really Yosef) and his brothers in Parshas Mikeitz, the Torah describes three different ways he frightened them.

First, he claimed they were [spies](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.42.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) (מרגלים).
Second, he [hid their silver](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.42.25?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) in their saddle bags, for them to find later.
Third, he [hid his cup](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.44.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) (גביע) in Binyamin's saddle bag.

The brothers saw these as Divine messages. On the first they [said](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.42.21?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en),

> “Alas, we are being punished on account of our brother, because we
> looked on at his anguish, yet paid no heed as he pleaded with us. That
> is why this distress has come upon us.”

On the third they [said](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.44.16?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en),

> Judah replied, “What can we say to my lord? How can we plead, how can
> we prove our innocence? God has uncovered the crime of your servants.
> Here we are, then, slaves of my lord, the rest of us as much as he in
> whose possession the goblet was found.”

So for each of those, they had a very clear interpretation of what they had done wrong - not listening to their brother's cries, selling him as a slave - that led to Hashem sending them this suffering.

But the one in the middle, the silver in the saddle bags, is perplexing. They know it's from Hashem, but they [don't understand](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.42.28?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) it:

> As one of them was opening his sack to give feed to his ass at the
> night encampment, he saw his money right there at the mouth of his
> bag.   And he said to his brothers, “My money has been returned! It is
> here in my bag!” Their hearts sank; and, trembling, they turned to one
> another, saying, *“What is this that God has done to us?”*... [and [later](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.42.35?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)]:
> As they
> were emptying their sacks, there, in each one’s sack, was his
> money-bag! When they and their father saw their money-bags, they were
> dismayed... [and [later]](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.43.23?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):
> But the men were frightened at being brought into Joseph’s house. “It
> must be,” they thought, “because of the money replaced in our bags the
> first time that we have been brought inside, as a pretext to attack us
> and seize us as slaves, with our pack animals.”

But the Viceroy never brings it up at all! [His servant] [brushes it aside completely](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.43.23?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> He replied, “All is well with you; do not be afraid. Your God, the God
> of your father’s [house], must have put treasure in your bags for you.
> I got your payment.”

I understand that Yosef was messing with them - very effectively! - but is there someone who explains more about the point of the second time he scares them?

Comment: I don't have an answer. But I'll add that this whole section of Genesis needs more analysis in general. It's stunning to me how Levi (the ancestor of Moses) has no role in the Judah/Joseph narrative. He does not speak and he does not do anything. It's interesting how Reuben has a few quotes in the Joseph narrative, as he is probably competing against Judah for the birthright blessing.

Comment: @Taylor I see your point, but see Rashi: https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.42.27?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en "AND THE ONE OPENED HIS SACK — This was Levi who remained alone (one) being without Simeon his companion". And see also https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.42.24?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en

Comment: Simeon seems cursed in a sense. He is the "second" son/tribe of Israel. "Seconds" are always cursed - the second day of creation, the second patriarch Isaac, etc. I will say that I think that Simeon and Levi got the best blessing in Genesis 49. They are "brothers" while most of all the other sons of Jacob are compared to animals.

Comment: @Taylor Isaac was cursed?

Comment: I don't know. Some things are good about Isaac, some things are bad. Isaac stayed in the Holy Land all of his life plus he lived longer than Abraham and Jacob. However, everyone does mistreat Isaac. His father, his wife, his sons, etc. Even the Torah text gives him little page time and attention compared to all the other main characters of Genesis.

Comment: @Taylor Chazal call Yitzchak the midah of "gevurah", however that is translated. I write about it here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jOtLBlWkshqR5eu8OFSWpV_kxabphg88/view?usp=sharing. Maybe a better description of him is that he is the one who completely lets Hashem run the world.